# Understanding RRSIG DNS query

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec

Is the presence of RRSIG highly uncommon? I tried to fetch RRSIG records for many popular domains including trying out different resolver. I didn't get any RRSIG records in the answer section.

```
dig @1.1.1.1 aws.com A +dnssec
dig @8.8.8.8 google.com A +dnssec
dig @8.8.8.8 aws.com A +dnssec
dig @8.8.8.8 icloud.com A +dnssec
dig @8.8.8.8 zoom.us A +dnssec
```

The answer section in the result never contains an RRSIG record. Am I doing something wrong? Or is RRSIG something that is not used a lot for security while fetching DNS records?

Comment: related: https://dnssec-name-and-shame.com - DNSSEC continues to impose operational requirements that many deem not worth the potential benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Your commands look fine, but there are a lot of zones (including many high profile ones) which are just not signed.

The way validation normally works is that both "correct signature" and "part of unsigned zone" (as indicated in the delegation) are treated as OK, while "incorrect/missing signature" will be treated as a validation error.